# Why can borrowed string literal outlive its owner by faking a lifetime?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I understand that a borrow cannot outlive the existence of the thing it points to, to eradicate the dangling pointers.

A borrow or an alias can outlive the owner by faking the lifetimes:

```
fn main() {
    let e;
    let first = "abcd";
    {
        let second = "defgh";
        e = longest(first, second);
    }
    println!("{}", e);
}

fn longest<'a>(first: &'a str, second: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if first.len() > second.len() {
        first
    } else {
        second
    }
}
```

Result:

```
defgh
```

In the above example, the variable `e` has a longer lifetime than the `second` variable and clearly the `first` & `second` variables lifetimes are different.

When `e` is initialized with `longest(first, second)` it gets the `second` variable whose lifetime to function call is faked as it is equal to `first` but it is confined to the block and it is assigned to `e` which will outlive the `second`. Why is this OK?

Comment: _"A borrow or an Alias can outlive the owner by faking the life time tags."_ — what does that mean? Rust doesn't let you fake anything, unless you resort to `unsafe` code.

Comment: I'm no expert, but my guess is that is ultimately because both `first` and `second` have `'static` lifetimes. The string literals are baked into the executable, so the references to them are always valid. If you got `second` from a function call of non-static lifetime I assume this wouldn't work.

Comment: What do you think the "owner" is in this case?

Comment: See also [How does the lifetime work on constant strings / string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31230585/155423)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to the fact that both of these have the `'static` lifetime.

Here's an example that doesn't work because the `str` here does not live for the life of the program like a `&'static str` does.
The only change is the following line: `let second = String::from("defgh");` and the next line where it is passed to the longest function.

```
fn main() {
    let e;
    let first = "abcd";
    {
        let second = String::from("defgh");
        e = longest(first, &second);
    }
    println!("{}", e);
}

fn longest<'a>(first: &'a str, second: &'a str) -> &'a str {
    if first.len() > second.len() {
        first
    } else {
        second
    }
}
```

Here's the error:

```
error[E0597]: `second` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:28
  |
6 |         e = longest(first, &second);
  |                            ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     }
  |     - `second` dropped here while still borrowed
8 |     println!("{}", e);
  |                    - borrow later used here
```

More information can be found in [Static - Rust By Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick reply. Now I get it.Then that means <'a> are just relative quantities at the function signature level. Those tags doesn't make much sence at the function level but they makes more sence at the catching return value site? because a function doesn't know who will call, what kind of references.

Comment: @PKChem In this specific case, the lifetime `'a` is determined by the compiler to be the shorter lifetime of the two string slices. Since in your original example both strings had static lifetime, `'a` is inferred to be `'static`, and the return value is also `'static`. The local variable `second` does not own the string slice – it's just another borrow, and it does not matter that a different borrow goes out of scope, as long as the data you are referring to is still there.