# Reading bytes from a file and parsing them with `pom` parser library

Tags: file, rust, borrow-checker, borrowing

I'm trying to write a parser with [pom](https://github.com/J-F-Liu/pom), which is great - no problems writing the parsers and feeding in string literal as test data. However, when I try to run it bytes from a file, it chokes;

```
108 |     fn parse_files() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
109 |         let byte_vec: Vec<u8> = std::fs::read("assets/valid_so_far.idl")?;
110 |         let byte_slice: &[u8] = &byte_vec;
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
111 |         let idl_parser = idl();
112 |         let parse_result = idl_parser.parse(byte_slice)?;
    |                            ---------------------------- argument requires that `byte_vec` is borrowed for `'static`
113 |         
114 |         Ok(())
115 |     }
    |     - `byte_vec` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I don't see what's going wrong here. I can't interpret the compiler error here and I don't understand why the lifetimes aren't OK here.

The `parse` function on line 109 has this signature:

```
fn parse(&self, input: &'a [I]) -> Result<O>

pub type Result<O> = ::std::result::Result<O, Error>;
```

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the `Error` returned by `parse`. Maybe from compiler's point of view, it could hold reference to the input, so it must not outlive it by being returned... Could you share more of the parser itself?

Comment: Does it compile if you `match` the result of `idl_parser.parse(byte_slice)` manually, anc convert an `Err` to something that surely does not refer to `byte_slice`?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> no problems writing the parsers and feeding in string literal as test data.

This works because all string literals have [the `'static` lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#the-static-lifetime). When you switch to read from a file instead, the latent `'static` is gone. The behavior of the code actually changes so that it triggers the error.

The question is then why your parser implementation expects a `'static` input in the first place. I suspect that the example given in the `pom` read-me file is to be blamed here. For example it has the following code:

```rust
use pom::Parser;

fn space() -> Parser<u8, ()> {
    one_of(b" \t\r\n").repeat(0..).discard()
}
```

`pom::Parser<u8, ()>` is actually an alias for `pom::parser::Parser<'static, u8, ()>`. If it were to be written as:

```rust
use pom::parser::Parser;

fn space<'a>() -> Parser<'a, u8, ()> {
    one_of(b" \t\r\n").repeat(0..).discard()
}
```

then it should be able to handle both `'static` and non-`'static` input. Make similar changes to your parser code and it will work again.

Comment: *This works because the const r-value like literal is subject to static promotion,* — this isn't relevant here. String literals are **always** `&'static str`. [How does the lifetime work on constant strings / string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31230585/155423)

Comment: this is exactly right! I had a `use pom::* \n use pom::Parser` block at the top of the file. Removing the second line fixed it

Comment: sorry - that should read `use pom::parser::*; use pom::Parser`

Answer (score 2):

The `pom::Parser<I, O>` is alias for `pom::parser::Parser<'static, I, O>`. So the `'a` lifetime in the `parse` function is actually `'static` if you are using this alias. Use the `pom::parser::Parser` struct directly with custom (possibly elided - you don't have to write it) lifetime.

Comment: thanks for this! You're spot on -- sorry I couldn't mark your answer as correct too.